How to wait for the model to load in Roblox? (lua)
How to wait for the model to load? I have a very simple code but 2 out of 3 times when I lunch the game I get an error Players.Alex.PlayerGui.AllSeeingEye:120: attempt to index nil with 'Position'. 1 time out of 3 it works.
local EyeModel = workspace:WaitForChild("EyeBox"):WaitForChild("EyeBoxModel")
local EyePosition = EyeModel.PrimaryPart.Position

I tried adding WaitForChild for the folder (EyeBox) and Model (EyeBoxModel). But not helping. Using a while loop sounds like a bad idea...

Your code can find the EyeModel successfully, but it doesn't have the PrimaryPart property set when it errors.
This can be caused by StreamingEnabled->Atomic or because you're setting PrimaryPart around the same time as when you're trying to access it. This would cause a race condition.
Is the name of the PrimaryPart always the same? Then you can consider doing a :WaitForChild("") for the PrimaryPart's name as well. This is the easiest and cleanest solution.
